# AWS IAM policy to deny permissions to any EC2 instances inside of autoscaling group or ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS cluster that is of EC2 launch type and an autoscaling group to automatically adjust the number of EC2 nodes in the cluster.

It's easy enough to write an IAM policy to Deny all access to the cluster and the ASG. I would also like to restrict any non-read `ec2` IAM permissions to the EC2 instances themselves that are launched as part of this cluster. Is that possible? I can't use instance IDs since the number of instances will be dynamically changing.

Here is an example IAM policy. As you can see, `Resource` is defined as one instance id, which will not work for my case.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789000:instance/i-123456789"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What you trying to achieve, if you looking to restrict the access on ec2 as a part of asg then you can do it by security group in launch configuration for ASG then automatically all instances will inherit the same security group with restriction.

Comment: What do you mean by "deny access"? Are you referring to ssh/RDP access, or access to a web app running on the instances? What do you mean by "non-read access to the EC2 instances"?

Comment: I am talking about IAM permissions in the `ec2` namespace. Anything that is not a "read only" permission. The exact list is not important. My question is about how to target the IAM policies to EC2 instances that are part of an ECS cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the instances launched by the ASG will have tags that you can identify them by. You should be able to apply policies based on said tags.